# Cardinality and surjective functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $A$ denote a set and $P(A)$ be the power set. By [definition](http://www.cs.bsu.edu/homepages/fischer/math215/cardinality.pdf) for cardinalities $|A|\le|B|$ iff there exists an injection $A \hookrightarrow B$. Note that there is an obvious surjection $P(A) \to A$.

Without the axiom of choice now can there also be a surjection $A \to P(A)$?

Comment: There isn't one, with or without AC. See [Cantor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Cantor's theorem does not depend on the axiom of choice.

The proof is really constructive from this point of view. Given a function from $A$ to $\mathcal P(A)$ we construct a set which is not in its image.

Comment: The set Asaf mentions is typically $\{a: a \notin f(a)\}$. You can try assuming that it is $f(b)$ for some $b$. Is $b \in f(b)$?